# JSF managed bean & Taglib

Tags: jsp, jsf, jstl, websphere-portal

I am trying to create a portlet `renderURL` to navigate to another portal page, which has a portlet. This is fine. But I want to pass a parameter in the URL, which is also fine. But I want to pass a value in parameter which is in managed bean.

So, it's dynamic parameter value.

```
<portlet-ext:portalRenderURL var="myURL" contentNode="NewPage">
    <portlet-ext:urlParam name="name" value=""/>
</portlet-ext:portalRenderURL>
```

HERE in `urlParam`, value should be something like `#{managedBean.name}`.

I am trying to create link on the "Name" so that the "name" I click, that value should be passed onto "NewPage" portlet so it can show details for that particular name.

Thank you

Comment: what is the problem, doesn't it work if you put in value of urlParam the attribute of managed bean? do you use this code in jsp?

Comment: Yes, I have tried putting code in JSP, assinging value="#{managedBean.name}" but it doesnt work. Anyway, it should not work as per my understanding as it's JSF EL and this tag is IBM's Java taglib.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got this right.

Used IBM libraries in managed bean to generate the link to the page and using that into JSF's commandLink tag. And also passign parameter to it using f:param tag.

This passes parameter value which is stored in the managed bean.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what library are you using to get access to the portlet-ext:portalRenderURL tag?  What version of WebspherePortal are you using?

Comment: Okay, I was trying to generate a link which takes to a new page with passing a dynamic parameter value ( generated at page generation ! ). But that was not working with <%@taglib uri="http://www.ibm.com/xmlns/prod/websphere/portal/v61/portlet/ibm-portlet-ext" prefix="portlet-ext" %> Hence I was looking for backend solution where in I can generate an URL to a page and pass on the parameter and I got a wp.l2.urlhelper.jar which has URL utility classes which helped me. Let me know if you need more information.